# Get the implementation type for an interface in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice-3

I'm using Guice 3 to do dependency injection.

I have a particular use case where I need to know what implementation type has been bound to the interface. Is there a mechanism is Guice that allows us to do this?

Comment: `.getClass().getName()`?...  But, kinda flies in the face of dependency injection principles...

Comment: I can't do .getClass() because I don't even have an instance of the object I'm trying to find the class of. I suppose I can instantiate a mock instance and then do that. I also realize that it flies in the face of dependency injection. But I need this to be able to correctly write class information into a Sequence File in hadoop.

Answer (score 2):

For such purposes Guice provides Extensions SPI.

You need to extend the DefaultBindingTargetVisitor (if you wish to override selective methods) and override the visit(Binding binding) you wish to inspect.

```
public class MyBindingsVisitor extends DefaultBindingTargetVisitor<Object, String>{

    public String visit(InstanceBinding<? extends Object> binding){
        Key<? extends Object> key = binding.getKey();
            System.out.println("Key :" + key.getTypeLiteral());
            System.out.println("Annotation : " + key.getAnnotation());
            System.out.println("Source : " + binding.getSource());
            System.out.println("Instance : "+binding.getInstance().toString());
            return visitOther(binding);
    }
}
```

Now, we need the injector to visit the bindings.

```
for(Binding<?> binding : injector.getBindings().values()){
    System.out.println(binding.acceptTargetVisitor(new MyBindingsVisitor()));
}
```

These bindings are complete bindings and hence are termed as the Injector Bindings.